Noise added by an amplifier when deriving Friis's formula
I have been asked to derive the equivalent noise factor for a cascaded system of two amplifiers. Here is the figure of the system (assuming a general configuration where \$ G_1 \$ and \$ G_2 \$ are the gains of the amplifiers, and  \$ F_{1} \$ and  \$F_2\$  are their respective noise figures, \$ T_{1} \$ and  \$T_2\$  are noise temperature of two amplifiers and \$T_0\$ is the source noise temperature):
$$
\text{Input} \rightarrow \left[ \text{Amplifier 1: } G_1, F_1, T_1 \right] \rightarrow \left[ \text{Amplifier 2: } G_2, F_2, T_2 \right] \rightarrow \text{Output}
$$
My Derivation:

Noise at the Input of the First Amplifier:
$$
   N_{\text{in}} = kT_0B\tag1
   $$

Noise Added by the First Amplifier:
$$F_1 = \frac{(SNR_{input1})}{(SNR_{output1})} = \frac{S_i/(kT_0B)}{G_1S_i/(kT_0B + N_{x1})}$$
\$
   N_{x1} = (F_1 - 1) N_{\text{in}}\tag2
   \$

Now considering second amplifier:
$$F_2 = \frac{(SNR_{input2})}{(SNR_{output2})} = \frac{G_1S_i/(G_1N_{in}+N_{x1})}{G_1G_2S_i/(G_1G_2N_{in}+G_2N_{x1}+N_{x2})}\tag3$$
By substituting (1) and using the result in (2)
$$F_2 =  \frac{G_1S_i/(G_1F_1kBT_0)}{G_1G_2S_i/(G_2G_1F_1kBT_0+N_{x2})}\tag4$$


Sorry if something is unclear and thanks for your responses. My questions are

Can I use the result obtained in equation (2) to substitute as \$N_{x2} = (F_2-1)N_{in}\$?

If yes, what is \$N_{in}\$: is it \$kBT_0\$  like in (1), or  \$kBT_2\$?


When I used the formula (4) to find \$N_{x2}\$, it gives me unexpected results.


This is a standard academic problem and is exactly described in Pozar's Microwave Engineering. Do you have access to this textbook?

It would be easier to find SNRoutput1 and SNRoutput2 and then plug that in, instead of chaining the noise terms through the system
